# One to one relationship with Entity Framework Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I'm having trouble with reverse navigation on one of my entities.

I have the following two objects:

```
public class Candidate
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long CandidateId { get; set; } 
    ....

    // Reverse navigation
    public virtual CandidateData Data { get; set; }
    ...

    // Foreign keys
    ....
}

public class CandidateData
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long CandidateDataId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long CandidateId { get; set; }

    // Foreign keys
    [ForeignKey("CandidateId")]
    public virtual Candidate Candidate { get; set; }
}
```

Now my foreign key navigation on  the CandidateData object works fine. I am having trouble getting the reverse navigation for the candidate object to work (if that's even possible).

This is my OnModelCreating function:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Candidate>()
        .HasOptional(obj => obj.Data)
        .WithOptionalPrincipal();

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

It's close to working except in the database I get two columns that link to the CandidateId. I get the one I from the POCO object the I get another column  Candidate_CandidateId I assume was created by the modelBuilder.

I am quiet lost at the moment. Can someone please shed some light on what's going on?

Comment: Why do you define additional field like 
[Required]
public long CandidateId { get; set; }

Remove it and your problems will be gone

Comment: I think your relation should be modelBuilder.Entity<Candidate>().HasOptional(obj => obj.Data).WithRequired(e => e.Candidate); BTW: try to not mix fluent api and attributes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The One to One problem....
The issue is EF and CODE First, when 1:1 , for the dependent to have a Primary key that refers to the principal.   ALthough you can define a DB otherwise and indeed with a DB you can even have OPTIONAL FK on the Primary.  EF makes this restriction in Code first.  Fair Enough I think...

TRy this instead:   IS have added a few **opinions** on the way which you may **ignore** if you disagree:-)

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace EF_DEMO
{
class FK121
{
    public static void ENTRYfk121(string[] args)
    {
        var ctx = new Context121();
        ctx.Database.Create();
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
public class Candidate
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]// best in Fluent API, In my opinion..
    public long CandidateId { get; set; }
 //   public long CandidateDataId { get; set; }// DONT TRY THIS... Although DB will support EF cant deal with 1:1 and both as FKs
    public virtual CandidateData Data { get; set; }  // Reverse navigation

}
public class CandidateData 
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] // best in Fluent API as it is EF/DB related 
    public long CandidateDataId { get; set; }   // is also a Foreign with EF and 1:1 when this is dependent
   // [Required]
   // public long CandidateId { get; set; }   // dont need this... PK is the FK to Principal in 1:1
   public virtual Candidate Candidate { get; set; } // yes we need this
}
public class Context121 : DbContext
{
    static Context121()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Context121>());
    }
    public Context121()
        : base("Name=Demo") { }
    public DbSet<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CandidateData> CandidateDatas { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Candidate>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<CandidateData>()
                    .HasRequired(q => q.Candidate)
                    .WithOptional(p=>p.Data) // this would be blank if reverse validation wasnt used, but here it is used
                    .Map(t => t.MapKey("CandidateId"));    // Only use MAP when the Foreign Key Attributes NOT annotated as attributes
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you, this has more or less solved the problem for me. 
Though I would still like to have the CandidateId field available to me to edit on the fly and without having to load up the Candidate  object. (Or am I interpreting this incorrectly?) 

Thanks again, William.

Comment: If you still want the foreign key, you could keep CandidateId as a property on CandidateData, and instead of calling .Map(t => t.MapKey("CandidateId")) use .HasForeignKey(t => t.CandidateId)

Would that not work?

Comment: @NathanaelSchulte That does not work, unfortunately. Why you are unable to do that, I have no idea. The .HasForeignKey() method is only accessible when using a many. The problem with the approach by phil soady, is that the foreign key, CandidateId, must then not be exposed as an explicit property of the model i.e. CandidateId cannot be defined in the CandidateData class.

Answer (score -2):

I think that the foreign key should be created as:
.Map(t => t.MapKey("CandidateDataId")) because thsi foreign key will be placed in Candidate table...

Waht do you think?