# One-to-One in table per hierarchy

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public class BasePage
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Region : BasePage
{        
    public virtual MapCoordinates Map { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Place: BasePage
{        
    public virtual MapCoordinates Map { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class MapCoordinates
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("BasePage")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual BasePage BasePage { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Getting this exception on SaveChanges:

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
    public class BasePage
    {        
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual MapCoordinate Map { get; set; }
        ...
    }

    public class Region : BasePage
    {                   
        ...
    }

    public class Place: BasePage
    {        
        ...
    }

    public class MapCoordinate
    {
        [Key]
        public int BasePageId { get; set; }
        ...
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BasePage>()
                    .HasRequired(e => e.MapCoordinate)
                    .WithRequiredPrincipal();

        modelBuilder.Entity<BasePage>().ToTable(BasePages);
        modelBuilder.Entity<MapCoordinate>().ToTable(MapCoordinates);
    }
```

check out these links :

[Associations in EF Code First: Part 4 – Table Splitting](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/24/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-4-table-splitting.aspx)

[Associations in EF Code First: Part 5 – One-to-One Foreign Key Associations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx)

[Code First and Fluent API one to one relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809861/code-first-and-fluent-api-one-to-one-relationship)

Comment: I don't want BasePage to have Map, only several derived classes should have it.

Comment: you want have table splittings?

Comment: I keep BasePage with it's derived classes (Region, Place etc) in one table, and Map in another one.

Comment: ok , I think in MapCoordinate navigate to region and place instead of BasePage and you couldn't use table splitted between basePage and MapCoordinate , then in MapCoordinate you must have two foreign key, One for region and one for place.

Comment: yeah, that probably will work, but looks like ugly solution, coz in fact I don't need two foreign keys.

Comment: yes of course ,but if you use navigation in drived class instead base class , you  forced use 2 foreign key, the course i agree using table splitted between Basepage and MapCoordinate.